# Failed stop, Android app with TarsosDSP

Tags: android, button, audio, record

I want to implement an android app using TarsosDSP package on this link:

https://github.com/srubin/TarsosDSP/releases/tag/TarsosDSPAndroid-v3-MAD

I created two buttons for startRecording and stopRecording,  my app does "start" but doesnn't "stop". My MainActivity is this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button start;
    private Button stop;

MicrophoneAudioDispatcher audioDispatcher = new MicrophoneAudioDispatcher(44100, 2048, 1024);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setButtonHandlers();


        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btStart);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btStop);
}

    private void setButtonHandlers() {
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btStart)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btStop)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    }




    private void startRecording() {
        audioDispatcher.run();
       }

    private void stopRecording() { 
        audioDispatcher.stop();
    }

private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.btStart:{

                startRecording();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.btStop:{

                stopRecording();

                break;

            }
            }
        };
    };
}
```

The class "MicrophoneAudioDispatcher" is on this link:

https://github.com/srubin/TarsosDSP/blob/master/src/be/hogent/tarsos/dsp/MicrophoneAudioDispatcher.java

I don't understand this error. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first step would be to make sure that `stopRecording` actually is called (e.g. by adding some log prints).

Answer (score 4):

You have to initial a thread for AudioDispatcher instead to call AudioDispatcher.run() directly.

```
dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(22050, 1024, 0);
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(new PitchProcessor(PitchProcessor.PitchEstimationAlgorithm.FFT_YIN, 22050, 1024, new PitchDetectionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handlePitch(PitchDetectionResult pitchDetectionResult,
                                AudioEvent audioEvent) {
            final float pitchInHz = pitchDetectionResult.getPitch();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mFrequencyView.setText(String.valueOf(pitchInHz));
                }
            });
        }
    }));
    new Thread(dispatcher, "Audio Dispatcher").start();
```

The thread will keep running until you call AudioDispatcher.stop(). It is important to avoid the thread remains on background.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    dispatcher.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the link you mentioned (TarsosDSPAndroid-v3-MAD) is a TarsosDSP fork that is compatible with Android. Since some time it isn't needed anymore, as described on [official site](http://0110.be/posts/TarsosDSP_on_Android_-_Audio_Processing_in_Java_on_Android):

> the fork of TarsosDSP kindly provided by GitHub user srubin, created for a programming assignment at UC Berkley, is not needed any more.

And what relates to your main question, you shouldn't manually call `run()` of AudioDispatcher, it should be called from separate thread like mentioned in the link above, something like this:

```
new Thread(dispatcher,"Audio Dispatcher").start();
```